# How to find a pattern among several different lines using python

Tags: python, string

I have three lines like below - what I want to do is to print `found` if at least 5 characters of the last 15 characters in the upper line have `|` character under themselves (meaning these characters bind to the characters in the third line)

```
5'      TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGTGCGTATTCTCAGTCAGTTGAAGTGATACAGAA
            ::     :::       ::        : :     : ||||| :          
3'          ATTCAGCCTGCACTCGTTACCGAGGCATGACAGAGAATTCACGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG
```

So far I have ended up with this script that can find specific patterns but I have not been able to expand it to find what I just mentioned in the question - it would be great if someone could help me to expand the code below - thank you.

```
import re

in_str = '''
5'      TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGTGCGTATTCTCAGTCAGTTGAAGTGATACAGAA
            ::     :::       ::        : :     : ||||| :          
3'          ATTCAGCCTGCACTCGTTACCGAGGCATGACAGAGAATTCACGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG'''

in_str = re.sub(r'^\s*', "", in_str)
lst = re.split(r'\n', in_str)

acgt = set(['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'])
for idx in range(min([len(s) for s in lst])):
    if lst[0][idx] in acgt and lst[1][idx] == '|' and lst[2][idx] in acgt:
        print('found!')
        break
```

Based on the structure of the three lines the output of the script should be `found` since the 5 characters (from the last 15 characters of the upper string) has `|` under themselves.

Comment: Are we using mono-spaced fonts? in that case we can simply check the second line and if 5 pipes found in last 15 chars of second line then we can mark it as found.

Comment: I think that will not work because based on the position of the bindings the space after the ```|``` can differ - so I think defining that at least 5 ```|``` should be under the last 15 characters of the first string can be more consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this. First slice the second line based on the length of first line and then count the occurrence of `|` in that slice.

```
in_str = '''
5'      TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGTGCGTATTCTCAGTCAGTTGAAGTGATACAGAA
            ::     :::       ::        : :     : ||||| :          
3'          ATTCAGCCTGCACTCGTTACCGAGGCATGACAGAGAATTCACGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG'''

lines = in_str.strip().split("\n")
first_line_length = len(lines[0]) # 62
valid_char_start_index = (first_line_length - 15 if first_line_length > 15 else 1) - 1  # 46

required_slice = lines[1][valid_char_start_index:first_line_length]  # : ||||| :   #
occurrence_of_pipe_in_slice = required_slice.count("|")  # 5
if occurrence_of_pipe_in_slice >= 5:
    print("found")
```

In case the mapping is done in the beginning as mentioned in the comment, we can do something like this:

```
import re

in_str = '''
5'     TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGGTGTAATCGTTCCGCTTGAATGTACGTCATGAA
            |||||   ::  :    ::    ::  :       :       ::      
3' ATTTGCAGTACACTCGTTACCGAGGCATGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG'''

lines = in_str.strip().split("\n")


first_line_prefix = re.match(r"\d\'\s+", lines[0]).group()  # "5'     "
third_line_prefix = re.match(r"\d\'\s+",lines[2]).group()  # "3' "

if len(first_line_prefix) < len(third_line_prefix): # To make sure that which ever line starts first we are picking correct index
    valid_char_start_index = len(first_line_prefix)
else:
    valid_char_start_index = len(third_line_prefix)
# valid_char_start_index = 3

try:
    required_slice = lines[1][valid_char_start_index:valid_char_start_index+15]  # '         ||||| '
except IndexError:
    required_slice = lines[1][valid_char_start_index:]  # in case the second line is smaller than the required slice it
    # will consider to the end of the line
occurrence_of_pipe_in_slice = required_slice.count("|")  # 5
if occurrence_of_pipe_in_slice >= 5:
    print("found")
```

To Summarise we can create a function where can take input parameter as where we want to look for the mapping beginning or in the end. And then determine start and end indices accordingly. From there in both cases rest of the process is same.

Comment: Thank you Roy - could you please a bit elaborate on this line of your code? ```valid_char_start_index = (first_line_length - 15 if first_line_length > 15 else 0) - 1  # 46``` thank you

Comment: There was a mistake on the line. Corrected it. I have just put it there to safegurd so that index is always a positive number in case the length is less than 15 digit. If we know for sure that the line will be always more than 15 char long we can simply do this `valid_char_start_index = first_line_length - 15-1`

Comment: dear @Roy thank you for your help - I have one more question if possible to get help from you. In some cases, there are bindings where the first part of the first string binds to the first part of the third string, is there a way similar to also print found if the first 15 characters of the third string have ```|``` above themselves? I pasted an example below - thank you

Comment: ```5'     TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGGTGTAATCGTTCCGCTTGAATGTACGTCATGAA
           |||||   ::  :    ::    ::  :       :       ::     
3' ATTTGCAGTACACTCGTTACCGAGGCATGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG```

Comment: Do we want to consider this `5' ` and `3 ` part in our first 15 chars? Or it should start from the alpha digits?

Comment: we should consider this - basically, the length of the first and second lines are always the same but the third line is being adjusted based on where it binds to the first string. I was trying to perform ```required_slice = lns[1][-n:-n]``` n based on the third string but because the lengths of the second and the third strings are different and there is a possibility that space can be after ```3'``` it did not work.

Comment: so basically I want to report ```found``` if the 5 ```|``` is in the last 15 characters of the first line or in the first 15 characters of the last line.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please have a look. I have assumed that `5' ` and `3' ` is not part of the first 15 digits and valid chars starts from the alpha digits. If that is not the case we need to set the `valid_char_start_index` to 0 and end_index to 15.

Comment: I just noticed that the second script of yours does not print ```found``` in this version ```5'           TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGGTGTAATCGTTCCGCTTGAATGTACGTCATGAA
                              :: :           :  ::    :  :   ||||||
3' ATTTGCAGTACACTCGTTACCGAGGCATGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG``` where the third line starts first but then ```|``` are at the end of the first line.

Comment: It should not, because the pipe chars are at the end. The first script identifies match at the end while the second script identifies at the beginning. We need to merge these two codes with either some parameterised input specifying which end we want to look at or just execute one after another to get a fully working solution. I have mentioned the same in the answer as well.

Comment: I just checked with the first script, it prints 'found'. There might be some edge cases, since I have not tested extensively. I am sure you will be able to rectify those in case if there is any.

Comment: In case we don't care whether they are at the beginning or at the end, but having five pipes at any end should result to `found` case, then we should just check for both of them in our final code and return true if any of them is found.

Comment: Yes exactly so - we need to print found if 5 pipe chars are below the 15 last chars of the first line or if 5 pipe chars are above the first 15 chars of the third line.

Comment: so in the latest example I shared, the second line starts first but then the pipe chars are at the end of the first line - these are outputs of a website and I have been tackling to handle this problem for a long time - I appreciate you help so much - thank you Roy

Comment: I have scripted considering whether these pipes are at the beginning of the second line or at the end. We might need to modify the code to tackle some edge cases. If pipes are at the end of the second line first script should be able to identify. Of they are at the beginning second script should be able to handle them. However it should work irrespective of which line starts first. Hope that clarifies the confusion. Do let me know in case of further clarification required.

Comment: I just merged both of your scripts and now it reports if the pipes are at the beginning or at the end - now I have to put them in a ```def```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `collections.Counter` class to help with counting:

```py
from collections import Counter

in_str = '''5'      TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGTGCGTATTCTCAGTCAGTTGAAGTGATACAGAA
            ::     :::       ::        : :     : ||||| :          
3'          ATTCAGCCTGCACTCGTTACCGAGGCATGACAGAGAATTCACGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG'''

# split string into lines:
strs = in_str.split('\n')
line1 = strs[0]
line2 = strs[1]
length1 = len(line1)
assert length1 >= 15 # we assume this
# last 15 characters of the first line
suffix1 = line1[length1-15:length1] # or line1[-15:]
# the 15 characters of the second line that are under the above characters
suffix2 = line2[length1-15:length1]
# count occurrences of each characters:
c = Counter(suffix2)
found = c.get('|', 0) >= 5
print(found)
```

Prints:

```
True
```